# Installing Popcorn Time SE

Tags: linux, linux-mint

After extracting `Popcorn-Time-linux32.tar.gz`, it shows these 4 files: `libffmpegsumo.so`, `nw.pak`, `package.nw` `e o Popcorn-time`.

How to install it on Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon 32-bit (v 2.2.16)?

Answer (score 2):

There might be some missing dependencies but you could always try and start it by issuing: `./Popcorn-time` in the directory you extracted it to.

Does that launch it or give any error messages or similar?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. This is the message:  ./Popcorn-Time
./Popcorn-Time: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: There are some hints around on the web that you might need to symlink an existing library file as per this.

`sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1`

That will of course only work if you got the libudev.so.1 file already installed. If not - try to find what package contains it on Linux Mint and start from there.

Hopefully this helps somewhat to get you further.

Comment: Hi @Swedish Mike.  Many thanks for your aid. It is working now!  I used your hint, but I had changed a bit. This is     "sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0"

Comment: Excellent news! Glad I was able to give you some help on the way. Hopefully you'll get some joy out of Popcorn-time ;-)

Comment: Is it still alive by the way? I heard that its servers are shutdown!

Answer (score 0):

first,

```
sudo apt-get install libudev1 && cd /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ && sudo ln -s libudev.so.1 libudev.so.0
```

then

```
$ cd ~/Popcorn-Time 
$ ./Popcorn-Time
```